# Why does "10ddd" equal "10" in my SQL query?

Tags: mysql

I'm experiencing a strange problem..

I got a table with the following fields:

```
id          smallint(5)
client_id   smallint(5)
name        varchar(50)
pass        varbinary(20)
```

I got at row with the following values:

```
id          = 5
client_id   = 10
name        = 'user'
pass        = '123'
```

But if I put some chars in after the client_id it still returns the row???

This query ought not to return anything... hmm

```
SELECT id
FROM db.user
WHERE client_id='10ddd' && name='user' && pass='123'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because mySQL auto-casts string values that are meant for int columns, cutting off all non-integer content.

In the process, `10ddd` gets truncated to `10`.

See [11.2. Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html)

I thought it's possible to turn off using one of the stricter [server modes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html), but I can't  see anything in the docs. Failing that, I'm not aware of a simple workaround!

Depending on where the value comes from, you could do a check on the value before you do the query, e.g. using `is_int()` if in PHP; exit if the value is not an integer.

Comment: @clarkk there seems to be no easy way! I added  a paragraph for how to work around it.